# While using "onChange" event on input type="checkbox", it is not working on single click and working on doubleclick

Tags: reactjs

on using `onChange` event on input `type="checkbox"`, it is not working on a single click and working on double-click

```
<input 
     type="checkbox" 
     name="category[]" 
     id={listItems.id} 
     ref="category" 
     value={listItems.id} 
     onChange={this.formValueChange} 
     defaultChecked={creatorFormData.category[index]}
/>
```

and on using onClick event, checkbox is not checked at all.

```
<input 
    type="checkbox" 
    name="category[]" 
    id={listItems.id} 
    ref="category" 
    value={listItems.id} 
    onClick={this.formValueChange} 
    defaultChecked={creatorFormData.category[index]}
/>
```

What can I use there?

Comment: Can you show 'formValueChange' function?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id={listItems.id} ref="category"
value={listItems.id} onChange={this.formValueChange.bind(this}
defaultChecked={creatorFormData.category[index]}/>
```

Comment: It is also not working, as I already bind this function inside constructor.   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    /**** binding to make context of this to class ***/
    this.formValueChange = this.formValueChange.bind(this);
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it using state value and checked attribute,

First set the default states,

```
this.state = {
    checkboxStatuses:[],
}
```

Now the change handler will be,

```
 formValueChange(index){
     let checkboxStatuses = [...this.state.checkboxStatuses];
     checkboxStatuses[index] = !checkboxStatuses[index]
     this.setState({checkboxStatuses:checkboxStatuses})
 }
```

While updating the category, you will have to update the state with the number of checkbox as equivalent to the number of categories,

let category = [];
if (this.props.stateValues.creatorData != undefined && this.props.stateValues.creatorData != '') {
    creatorFormData = this.props.stateValues.creatorData;

```
    this.setState({checkboxStatuses:[...creatorFormData].fill(false)});

    if (creatorFormData.categories != undefined && creatorFormData.categories != '') {
        category = creatorFormData.categories;
    } else if (creatorFormData.category == null) {
        creatorFormData.category = [];
    }
}
```

And the component should be like,

```
 const categoryList = category.map((listItems,index) =>
  <div className="col-12 col-md-3" key={listItems.id}>
    <div className="selectmultibtn">

      <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id={listItems.id} ref="category" value={listItems.id} onChange={(e)=>this.formValueChange(index)} defaultChecked={creatorFormData.category[index]}/>

      <label htmlFor={listItems.id}>{listItems.name}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I am using an array of category,

Comment: Ok, you mean, you have an array of input fields, in that case you will have to keep an array in state to keep track of the checked statuses

Comment: I have edited the code accordingly. Check the latest code

Answer (score 0):

I am using an array of category,

` let category = [];
    if(this.props.stateValues.creatorData != undefined && this.props.stateValues.creatorData != ''){
      creatorFormData = this.props.stateValues.creatorData;
      if(creatorFormData.categories != undefined && creatorFormData.categories != ''){
        category = creatorFormData.categories;
      } else if( creatorFormData.category == null) {
        creatorFormData.category=[];
      }
    }

```
const categoryList = category.map((listItems,index) =>
  <div className="col-12 col-md-3" key={listItems.id}>
    <div className="selectmultibtn">
      <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id={listItems.id} ref="category" value={listItems.id} onChange={this.formValueChange} defaultChecked={creatorFormData.category[index]}/>
      <label htmlFor={listItems.id}>{listItems.name}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
)`
```